# Issue with replace function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calling a servlet and it gives me a JSON response as below

```
{"check":"<table><tr><td>ID<\/td><\/tr><\/table>"}
```

Here I need to have only table element`(<table><tr><td>ID</td></tr></table>)` so I am using replace function to do. PFB the javascript code

```
var backendRes = "{"check":"<table><tr><td>ID<\/td><\/tr><\/table>"}";
var res = backendRes.replace('{"check":"',"").replace('\/','/');
alert('res:"+res);
```

I am getting Unexpected identifier error in 'backendRes' variable. I am unable to get the result. pls help me fix this issue.

Comment: `v` is a string or object? Can you fix your code in question?

Comment: it is a javascript variable only.

Comment: As of now, it's syntax error only. That's why I pointed that you need to fix your code, because it's not clear what type `v` has in the first place. `{` looks like an object, however it's missing closing `}`.

Comment: i updated it. Please check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but your script would be something like this

```
      var backendRes = "{"check":"<table><tr><td>ID<\/td><\/tr> <\/table>"}";
```

var res = backendRes.check;

Comment: i am not using check object here. all i need to do it replace the JSON response into "<table><tr><td>ID</td></tr></table>"

Comment: This is the way you get json value from key check. Try it once

Comment: @ezhil, I provided you the solution and you marked Mahesh answer as correct??????

Answer (score 1):

```
var backendRes = {"check":"<table><tr><td>ID<\/td><\/tr><\/table>"};

alert('res:'+backendRes.check);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/12641/)

Comment: this is json object you dont need to use string functions for this. Just use backend.check, it will give you the desired output.